# Magento 2.3.3: I am using valet-linux and struggling to set up multi-store in Magento

Tags: multistore, server-setup, multi-website, multidomain, multisite

As the title states I am using valet-linux and everything on single site/store works fine. The part I am struggling with is getting multi-store working with valet-linux.

I have tried adding different drivers in the driver folder for valet but not having much luck?

Anyone experienced with valet-linux?